# Dealing with cat and head in a bash loop

Tags: unix, cat, unix-head

I am trying to add two lines of text from one file to the beginning of a bunch of other files by using a for loop in the bash command line.

I tried this in the command line:

```
$for i in *.txt; do head -2 ../../041_R_def_c.txt > X; cat i >> X; \mv X i; done
```

but it gives me the error:

```
cat: i: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to just move one line to the beginning of the files:

```
$for i in *.txt; do echo "#c wavelength d %4.0f angstrom"|cat - i > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out i; done
cat: i: No such file or directory
cat: i: No such file or directory
cat: i: No such file or directory
```

I thought that i would carry the name of the .txt file, but I don't think that is what i is. How can I get i to carry the name of the file/play the role of the file?

Comment: For a brief moment, this question looked like animal abuse. :P

Comment: try `cat - $i` as you need a $ for variables after initialisation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, `i` is a variable, you need to access the contents of the variable with `$`, so it should be `cat $i >> X`.  Otherwise, it thinks you want to `cat` the file named `i`, which doesn't exist.  `$i` gives you the name stored inside the variable `i`.

You will run into the same issue with `mv`... You will want `\mv X $i`

Comment: You shouldn't need quotes unless there are spaces in the variable... but yes, this is certainly good practice.